# Instance does not have a volume attached at root

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, root, amazon-ami

I recently started trying out EC2 servers and came across an issue when trying to get an instance back up from a snapshot (which is another odd issue I had, because you can't change root snapshots in the launch setup) I tried quite a few of the answers on here and still nowhere...

[image: AWS shows that it is attached and assigned as xvda but that's not root i guess?]

Actually this is the first time I've ever just had to ask outright for any help on a forum because the internet has proved to be quite helpful these past 2+ years I've been on it.

More info: I terminated the instance thinking that stopping it still charges me, but wanted to still use the volume after so kept that. Then I created a new instance same everthing as the previous, detached the root volume and attached the old one as xvda but for some reason it's giving me this "Failed to start the instance i-omitted Invalid value 'i-*omitted*' for instanceId. Instance does not have a volume attached at root (/dev/xvda)"

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcOwi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is the issue? Does the instance boot? If it does than it indeed has a root volume attached - that's the `xvda` volume, however it may show as something else in the instance, perhaps `/dev/nvme0n1p1`.

Comment: Instance refuses to boot. "Failed to start the instance i-omitted Invalid value 'i-omitted' for instanceId. Instance does not have a volume attached at root (/dev/xvda)"

Answer (score 0):

You can try to attach your volume like this for your Linux instance:

[image]